# Applying different transformations to a polygon given a describing transformation matrix

Tags: matrix, rotation, 2d, translation, transformation

I have a 2D polygon and a 2D transformation matrix ***M*** that I use to transform the vertices of the polygon. The matrix may describe...

- rotation around ***z*** axis,
- scaling along ***x*** and ***y***,
- sheering along ***x*** and ***y*** axis,
- translation along ***x*** and ***y*** axis.

Since we are in 2D the transformation matrix is of type ***3x3***. Here as an example a translation matrix by vector ***t*** and a rotation by angle ***a***:

```
M_t = |1 0 t2|       M_r = | cos(a) sin(a)  0|
      |0 1 t1|             |-sin(a) cos(a)  0|
      |0 0 1 |             |   0      0     1|
```

In my custom framework I don't have any access to the matrix values but can apply other matrixes in a row:

```
vertice = ( M_r * M_t ) * vertice
```

The above formula rotates the vertice around (0, 0) by angle ***a*** and then translates it by vector ***t***. I know that matrix multiplications aren't commutative. So the order of multiplications is important.

**My problem** is now that I want to get a transformation matrix ***N*** that reflects a rotation ***R*** around the new center of the polygon, followed by a translation ***T***, after applying an unknown transformation matrix ***M***. Or in other words: I want to rotate and translate the polygon relative to its position and rotation given by ***M***.

I can imagine this way of doing it, incorporating an unknown rotation and translation as part of ***M***:

```
N = R * M * T
```

My questions are:

- Is that mathematically correct?
- What about an unknown sheering and scaling as part of ***M***?
- Is there a better way of doing this?